# How to create programmatically an AWS Console enabled user

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authentication

I'm trying to add programmatically a "working" AWS account via API.

Actually I'm performing this operations:

- Authentication
- CreateUser (login)
- CreateLoginProfile (password)

When I go on "AWS" console I get an error an if I look to the Accounts linked to the Organization I can't find my new account.
But if I go on https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/home the user is there.

Do I'm missing something? Is there any difference between USER and ACCOUNT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course USER and ACCOUNT are different. An account contains users and other resources (S3 bucket, EC2 instance).
If you want to create new AWS account, you need to use Organizations API.

See:

- [create-account in the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/create-account.html)
- [CreateAccount documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAccount.html)